# Find a gameobject base on its transform in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `transform` and want to find the `gameObject` which has that `transform`.

For example, how would I find the `gameObject` for

```
Vector3 myTransform = new Vector3(33,12,0);
```

Comment: `Transform` is not a `Vector3`. There is  position(`Vector3`), scale(`Vector3`) and rotation(`Quaternion`) which are under `Transform`. Which one do you mean?

Comment: transform.position

Comment: Does the object you are looking for have a collider, if so there is a very fast way to find it by using `Physics.OverlapShere`, see [this question and answer over on the unity fourms](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/383671/find-gameobject-at-position.html)

Answer (score 3):

Get all the transforms in a scene, then loop through all of them checking if their `transform.position` is equal to what you want:

```
Vector3 myVector = new Vector3(33,12,0);
Transform myTransform;
void start()
{
    Transform[] allTransforms = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Transform)) as Transform[];
    foreach (transform someTransform in allTransforms)
    {
        if(someTransform.position != myVector)
            continue;

        myTransform = someTransform;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work unless there is a compare method in Vector3.

Comment: `Transform.position` returns a `Vector3`, and `myVector` is also a `Vector3`, when you compare them in an if statement, it only returns `true` if both `Vector3`'s are the same. @jdweng

Comment: If you touch vector3's the slightest, float approximation might offset them a tiny bit. Its probably better to use Vector3.SqrMagnitude against a small known epsilon

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that implements

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Vector3> vector3 = new List<Vector3>();
            Vector3 myTransform = new Vector3(33, 12, 0);
            vector3.Add(myTransform);

            Vector3 results = vector3.Find(x => x == myTransform);
        }
     }
    public class Vector3 : IEqualityComparer<Vector3>
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }

        public Vector3(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
        public Boolean Equals(Vector3 a, Vector3 b)
        {
            return a == b;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Vector3 vector3)
        {
            return (vector3.x.ToString() + "^" + vector3.y.ToString() + "^" + vector3.z.ToString()).GetHashCode();
        }


    }







}
```

I Equality

Comment: Oh this is for Unity3D, this functionality is built in.